# Using "each" in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, determiners

I'm having a problem with presenting data in a table.

Example:

Item 1: Reading foreign novels

Group A = 5 participants, Group B = 3 participants, Group C = 3 participants

I'm wondering if it's correct to present the data this way using "**each**":

"Eleven participants mentioned that they read foreign novels to improve their English skill. There were five participants from group A and three participants from group B and group C **each**."

I'd like to know if "each" is used correctly in the sentence above. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, Rose. No; you'd say "There were five participants from group A and three participants each from group B and group C."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - That's exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: I suppose "There were five participants from group A and three participants from each of groups B and C" looks to have the more traditional grammar, but it's more formal.

Comment: Thank you Edwin.